# Hello world in Java: Understanding the concept versus in python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to learn Java now and this is the hello world program and it already have started to baffle me. I am used to python and I found [this](http://qatar.cmu.edu/~dfossati/15-121-spring12/resources/Java4Python.pdf) tutorial (ebook) simple and concise for programmers who have python background.

Hello world program in Java from the book:

```
public class Hello {

public static void main (String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
}
```

As the book says, the equivalent code for this in python is:

```
class Hello(object):
  @staticmethod
  def main(args):
     print "Hello World!"
```

I completely understand the python code. However, I have a problem with Java code and I want to be clear before I proceed further so that I get the root knowledge of language in my brain.

The book says (as copied from book):

> ...we have one parameter. The name of the parameter is args however,
>   because everything in Java must have a type we also have to tell the
>   compiler that the value of args is an array of strings. For the moment
>   You can just think of an array as being the same thing as a list in
>   Python. The practical benefitt of declaring that the method main must
>   accept one parameter and the parameter must be a an array of strings
>   is that if you call main somewhere else in your code and and pass it
>   an array of integers or even a single string, the compiler will flag
>   it as an error.

This does not make any sense to me. Why can I not pass anything since my function doesn't require anything? What happens if I just pass (String args).

Since I am completely newbie to Java, please bear with me.

Comment: I don't think the given Python code is equivalent in any way.  It may somehow reproduce the superficial structure, but the Python code doesn't even print "Hello World!" when run.

Comment: The python equivalent is ``print("Hello World!")``.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem like a very good explanation of Hello World in general. All the Java boilerplate is confusing enough without trying to explain all the benefits of static typing at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure the book's listed benefit (ie can't pass main an integer or a single string) is really even a benefit.  I think the one of the main reasons that main method has an array of Strings is so that it can accept an arbitrary number of command line parameters.

Comment: Frankly, if you're completely new to Java, I'd recommend just taking our word that all of this is meaningful and relevant, until you have more background and can understand what it's doing.  Trying to understand the _entire_ hello world program is a bit much.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If someone is familiar with Python, Java is hardly that big a stretch.

Comment: @Lattyware: I guess, the python code is right. My understanding is the book meant the class to be called without any of its instance like Hello.main("") which produces "Hello World!".

Comment: @Lattyware: I'm not convinced.  Understanding what's going on with classes, and what it means for a method to be public or static?  For your very first look, I'd stick to taking it on faith until you learn more about how Java does OO.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I agree with Lattyware. I assume I can borrow most of the basic of classes, inheritance and other concepts from python so I want to proceed by understanding the differences. I took the code as granted and tried to understand those later when I learned python. I don't want to do the same with Java now.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Are you implying Python doesn't have classes? Or static methods? I'm not saying there will not be newish concepts, but they are not difficult concepts to learn given the foundation of programming knowledge they will have available.

Comment: @Louis In my experience the more programming languages I learn, the easier it gets to learn another one. If you know Java or some similar OOP language and say some functional language (scheme in my case), python doesn't offer any really new concepts and was pretty easy to get fast into. And Java really doesn't have any concepts that python doesn't offer.

Comment: I'm saying that you should have done some playing beyond "hello world" before dealing with that stuff.  Meh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, Python uses "duck typing": it doesn't matter what type something is, only what it can do. As a result, you never need to declare types for your variables.

In Java, that's not true: every variable has a declared type, and the compiler enforces that type. Trying to store, for example, a `String` reference in an `int`-declared variable will produce a compile-time error. Proponents of duck typing claim that this decreases flexibility, but strong-typing enthusiasts point out that compile-time errors are easier to fix than run-time bugs.

But the same is true of your method arguments. Since your method requires an argument of type `String[]`, it must be provided an argument of type `String[]`. Nothing else will do.

Fortunately, since it's the `main` method, the Java interpreter takes care of passing in an argument: specifically, an array of the command-line args with which your program was executed. If you'd like to ignore it, feel free. Your program will run just fine without paying attention to the argument, but it's invalid if one isn't passed in.

(By the way, if this were any method but the `main` method, you'd be free to declare it with whatever argument types you'd like, including no arguments at all. But since the Java interpreter will be passing in an array of the command line arguments, this particular method must be prepared to accept them.)

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are passing in something. Whenever you run a java program, command line arguments are passed in as the `args` argument, so you need to accept those, even if you don't use them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are two things going on here. First, is function signatures - since you declare `main` to expect and accept only an array of strings, it'll raise an error if you try to pass it something else. But not because the function refuses to accept it, but because the compiler won't know what you're trying to call. See, you can have *multiple* functions with the same name, but different arguments. So if you were trying to call `main(1)`, the compiler would look for a function main that accepts one (or more) integers, not find it, and raise an exception.

The other thing going on here is that when you start a program, the compiler looks for this particular signature - `public static void main (String[] args)` and nothing else. Can't find it? The program won't run.

Comment: You didn't explain why main() needs to take an array of Strings, which was the question.

Comment: @Lattyware That's not the question. The question is "Why can I not pass anything since my function doesn't require anything?" which this answers

Comment: I would note that it's somewhat misleading to say the compiler "raises an exception".  It is a subtle but important difference that in Java, you have compile time and runtime errors, and only runtime errors actually raise exceptions; compile time errors just return errors from the compiler.  You can't, for instance, catch and handle the error presented here as you could in a completely interpreted language like Python.

Comment: @kyle_wm OK, I worded what I said poorly. What I mean is, the OP is asking why this is the case, so telling him that it's because *'main has to be like that'* is like telling someone who asks why the sky is blue 'because it's blue'. He knows you need to pass the argument, he is asking why that is the case.

Comment: And I thought I answered that, when talking about function signatures.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there is no top-level code as in Python (i.e. there is no direct equivalent to just

```
print('Hello world')
```

). Nevertheless, a Java program needs some kind of entry point so that it can start executing code. Like many other languages (i.e. C/C++, C#, Haskell), a [function with the name `main`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_(programming)) serves for this purpose and is called by the runtime (i.e. Java interpreter).

When calling the `main` function, the runtime uses a [certain number (and types) of arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_signature#Signature). The function must match these. You're free to then call other methods with any signature you like:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void hi() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    hi();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every program has an entry point/starting point from where its execution would start. Java searches for a specific method signature it will start from in a class to run your application which is the 'main' method.

```
public static void main(String args[]);
```

This must be implemented in order for you to start your program ( in a class you want to start off from). And because of this rule/restriction we must pass array of strings ( which are similar to list of strings in Python) as arguments.

Now for the second part, if your program does not require any parameters at startup, dont pass any. You will get args as an empty String array in main method. The following line would print out the length of arguments passed to your main method.

```
System.out.println("Length of arguments = " + args.length);
```

You might also want to look at [Sun's Java guide for starters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your function does not require anything (so it has no parameters) then you are allowed to avoid passing anything, this is done by declaring it as

```
void noArgumentsFunction() {
  // body
}
```

But the `main` function, that is a boiler plate, must accept an array of `String`s. That's why you are forced to declare the signature to accept it (and then ignore it in case). The funcion must accept this parameter because it's the [entry point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_%28programming%29) for your program and any Java program must support a array of parameters that is passed with command line (exactly as every C/C++ program, also if you are not forced to do it).

Comment: You didn't explain why ``main()`` needs to take an array of Strings, which was the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the main method is called by the JVM to start the program and passed the command line arguments. It can be called by Java code, but this is very rarely done.

Anyway, this is the signature of the method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

It says that it requires a parameter that is an array of Strings. If you call it like this:

```
main(new String[1]);
```

or this:

```
main(methodThatReturnsAStringArray());
```

it will work. But these will cause a compiler error:

```
main(new int[0]); 
main("test");
```

Because the type of the parameter in the call does not match the type the method signature requires. You *can* pass a null pointer:

```
main(null);
```

Because arrays are a reference type, and `null` is a valid value for all reference types. But then the method will have to test for that case, otherwise it will throw a `NullPointerException` when it tries to access the array.

Another thing you can do is overloading, by declaring *another* method:

```
public static void main (String args)
```

So when you call

```
main("test");
```

the compiler would determine that there is a method with a matching signature and call that.

Basically, the point of all this is that many programmer errors are caught by the compiler rather than at runtime (where they may only be discovered in some special circumstances if it's a rarely executed code path).

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your programme from command line, Commandline parameter can be more than one string.

eg.

Java myprogramme param1 param2 param3

all this parameters - param1, param2, param3 are passed as string[].

This is common for all program, who pass zero, one or more params.

As a programmer your responsibility to check those command line params.