# User input in Java versus python

Tags: java, python

Again problem with understanding Java. When I asked previous question about [Hello world in Java versus python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215225/hello-world-in-java-understanding-the-concept-versus-in-python), I received suggestion of taking the language as granted for a while till I don't get hang of it. However, I cannot take that approach and is baffled by some weird things in Java versus python.

Here is the program which takes input from user and convert F to degree Celsius in python.

```
def main ():
 fahr = input (" Enter the temperature in F: ")
 cel = ( fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0
 print " the temperature in C is : " , cel
```

This is pretty straightforward without any quirky things going on inside.

The example to do the same thing in Java:

```
import java . util . Scanner ;

 public class TempConv {
 public static void main ( String [] args ) {
 Double fahr ;
 Double cel ;
 Scanner in ;

 in = new Scanner ( System . in );
 System . out . println (" Enter the temperature in F: " );
 fahr = in . nextDouble ();

 cel = ( fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
 System . out . println (" The temperature in C is : " + cel );

 System . exit (0);
 }

 }
```

What I thought should happen was: Scanner was Java class/instance of class/object to take user input and with

```
Scanner in
```

created a new object to take user input. It turns out to be we are just declaring in to be of Scanner type in Java (Correct me if I am wrong).

Now, if it was python, we would have just called the method of the newly created Scanner object that takes input from the user. OMG, what is this in Java? We create

> new Scanner

object  and pass `System.in` as a parameter and assign it to

> in

again?

Can somebody please explain to me in pythonic terms, What is happening here and how and why it should differ from python so much?

Any creative suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @nikhil: I am trying to learn new things here. I would have appreciated a little explanation suggesting why it is meaningless rather than such a rude response.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: This is explained in chapter 1 of Any Java Introduction Text Ever Written.  Show some effort before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little garbled, but here's my attempt at an answer.  In Java, just like in Python, you need to instantiate a class before you can call methods on it.  In Python, you might do this:

```
myvar = MyClass(name="example")
```

In Java, the syntax is very similar:

```
in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And just like in Python, we can now call methods on it, such as:

```
fahr = in.nextDouble();
```

This is just about identical to what the equivalent Python code would look like.  It's possible I'm not understanding the source of your confusion, so if this doesn't help let me know and I'm happy to update things.

Comment: `Scanner` is a class that reads input from a stream (in this case, `System.in`, which is equivalent to Python's `stdin`).  The example is using the `Scanner` class to read a double value from the input. This is roughly equivalent to the `fscanf()` function in C.  See [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for details about the `Scanner` class.

Comment: Thanks larsks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the object declarations as an implicit assignment of None.  This would be pretty pointless in python, because variables don't have types, but their VALUES do (which is why declaring a variable w/o assigning it a value is pointless).  In Java, when you declare a variable, you make a promise as to what subset of types will be stored therein, and as there might be some code between making that promise and actually having a value to put in there, they are accomplished in separate statements.

Comment: Interesting... you say almost the exact same thing I do, yet I get -2 and you get +1...

Answer (score 1):

Java is a static typed language, you have to declare the type of a variable before you use it.

```
Scanner input; //This declare a variable of type Scanner but not assign anything to it yet
input = new Scanner(System.in); // This create a new object of Scanner type and assign it to the variable in
```

This can be shorten as

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Assuming we have a Scanner class in Python, the roughly-equivalent code is

```
input_obj = None
input_obj = Scanner()
```

Python is dynamic typed language, so you don't need to declare the type. The first line therefore don't serve any purpose, it can be and should be omitted, which result in

```
input_obj = Scanner()
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't think you really understand how programs and computers work.  You can think of it as `Scanner in` creates a label for a region in memory  named `in` of the correct size for a `Scanner` type object, then `in = new Scanner()` actually creates that object in that location in memory that was previously reserved.  You can think of it as roughly analogous to `in = None` `in = Scanner()` in Python, though that's not really quite correct.  The thing is that since Python is loosely typed, it handles all the bookkeeping behind the scenes, thus allowing you to do what is really multiple steps with a single line of code.

Comment: This is the most rude answer I could ever get! What do you mean by that? I am finding the difference in the language I am used to and I am trying to learn so what makes you think that I don't know "how programs and computers work".

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Because your question suggests that you don't.  Do you understand the process of reserving memory and then writing values to it?  When you create a variable in Python, it is more or less a pointer to an arbitrary piece of data whose type is defined when you actually assign a value.  In Java, you have to declare the type of data to be stored at that location ahead of time so that the interpreter can tell the OS how much space it needs, since that is determined at compile time instead of run time.

Comment: You should have firstly considered that I am trying to learn Java and I am used to python where I don't have to worry about memory management. You comments answers itself.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Java has managed memory too, however, if you don't really understand what is going on under the hood, you can't expect to really get the full value of any language.  Start with the basics, then build on top of that.

Comment: I wrote whole of my MS thesis with MATLAB without knowing what goes under the hood. Choices are different for everybody.

Comment: And therein is the difference between being a scripter and a programmer.  With some effort, you might actually become the later.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but the not the rudeness which you showed while answering. There is a difference between being a talented human being and humble human being. Everybody has some starting point. With little effort, I am sure you can be latter.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Your question is something like why do we do something this way in language X and another way in language Y.
These sort of questions aren't constructive, to learn about this the best way is to read any textbook.
All you've done here is start a mini flame war, I think this question should be closed.